# assets/ directory not being packaged into .apk from eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, android-ndk

I have the following directory structure in an app I'm porting to Android (ndk).

```
Project
 /src/ -- Location of my .java
 /jni/ -- Location of my Android.mk and Application.mk
 /assets/ -- Location where I put my raw data resources
 /code/ -- Location of actual c++ src code
```

The original structure had a "res" directory instead of "assets", but these were just my raw resources, didn't adhere to the android packaging/naming structure, so resulted in errors.

The problem is when I renamed it "assets" the errors in eclipse went away, but the assets were not included in the bin/Project.apk file.  When I do aapt l Project.apk, sure enough there is no "assets" items and the apk size is far too small anyway.

So I'm sure I missed a step after renaming the "assets" dir, where I tell eclipse to package these files, but I have no idea what it was.  Help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the same structure for one of my apps in Eclipse, with no special references in the manifest. Have you tried a full sweep refresh?

1. Right-click on the project, select "Refresh"
2. Select "Project" menu, then "Clean..."
3. Restart Eclipse

I've occasionally had projects of varying language in Eclipse which required all of the above 3 steps in order to fully update the project files, specifically when I made such changes as renaming folders or added completely new files.

Comment: I can only say that it has started working-- aapt l Project.apk gives the expected result.  I went into ant.properties and added asset.dir=assets ... but even when I tried removing that line to recreate the problem (to see what change I made affected the packaging), my apk still outputs correctly now.  So it's still a mystery, but it works.